# Trigger email firebase extension - error with nodemailer

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-extensions

I installed the extension to trigger emails on databse writes. My website has a simple 'Contact me' form, where i'm not expecting a lot of traffic, so I wanted to set-up a simple notification e-mail system.

However, i'm having a hard time getting the confgiuration right.

I configured a firebase trigger e-mail extension:

```
smtp connection URI: smtp://email:password@smtp.gmail.net:465
email documents collection: messages
default FROM address: Some Name <email>
```

On every contact form submit, I store the data to firestore in a following format:

```
let db = firebase.firestore();
db.collection("messages").add({
    from: "First Last <email>",
    to: "email",
    replyTo: "First Last <email>",
    message: {
        subject: "New message from website!",
        text: "some text"
    }
})
.then((docRef) => {
    console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
});
```

Document gets written to Firestore.

The error I see in functions log:

> ext-firestore-send-email-processQueue Error when delivering message=messages/vG9gviTCyh1Glxl1vBu1: Error: queryA EREFUSED smtp.gmail.net

Furthermore I see that Firestore collection has gotten a `delivery` object added to it with the same error.

Given the above, I think the code part is working - I successfully store the field in the Firestore and it triggers a cloud function. I think the issue is with configuration on either trigger email extension or in gmail settings.

Now, I didn't find much useful about this when googling (using GMAIL with Trigger email extension in firebase) and that's a hint that I may be off to a wrong start and perhaps should look into other options? If that's not the case, then what other settings may I check? I did create myself an app password in gmail, but I don't know where should I submit it in the trigger email extension. Would I also need to configure the gmail as a SMTP server in the Authentication templates configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Breaking down the error message,

- `queryA` - Submitting a query for a DNS A-Record
- `EREFUSED` - Was refused (threw an error - e.g. not found)
- `smtp.gmail.net` - the subject of the query

So in short, this is saying the web server `smtp.gmail.net` could not be found as it isn't registered.

Based on the documentation for [sending email using Gmail](https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600),

- If you are using a Google Workspace, you should use `smtp-relay.gmail.com` (10k daily message limit)
- If you are a regular Gmail user, you should use `smtp.gmail.com` (2k daily message limit)

If you plan on exceeding these limits, you should consider making use of a third-party mailing service.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, good catch on `.net` instead of `.com`. After changing it the error code turned to `Error: Unexpected socket close`. Any clues what may cause that one?

Comment: Looks like after enabling 2FA, I had to use the app password instead of plaintext password to authenticate from Trigger email configuration. After changing the Firebase extension to app password, I successfully sent an e-mail. Thank you!